# Mounting a vue instance with avoriaz, but cannot sinon spy on imported function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sinon, chai, avoriaz

I have the following component script (some irrelevant bits removed):

```
import api from '@/lib/api';

export default {
  methods: {
    upload (formData) {
      api.uploadFile(formData).then(response => {
        this.$emit('input', response.data);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

And I have the following test, which uses avoriaz to mount the Vue instance:

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import UploadForm from '@/components/UploadForm';

describe('upload', () => {
  it('passes form data to api.uploadFile', () => {
    const testFormData = { test: 'test' };
    const api = {
      uploadFile: sinon.spy()
    };
    const wrapper = mount(UploadForm);
    wrapper.vm.api = api;
    wrapper.vm.upload(testFormData);
    expect(api.uploadFile.called).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

My sinon spy is never called, and I've tried a couple different variations on the above.  What is the best way to spy on an imported function like this?  Or am I conceptually approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

You need to stub the api dependency, which is a dependency of the file. This can't be done through the vue instance, since api is not a part of the vue component.

You need to stub the file dependency.

**Solution**

One method to do this is to use [`inject-loader`](https://github.com/plasticine/inject-loader).

**Steps**

Install inject-loader

```
npm install --save-dev inject-loader
```

At the top of your file, import `UploadForm` with `inject-loader` and `vue-loader`:

```
import UploadFormFactory from '!!vue-loader?inject!@/components/UploadForm';
```

This is a factory function that returns `UploadForm` with dependencies stubbed.

Now, in your test you need to call `UploadFormFactory` with the dependency you want stubbed:

```
const api = {
  uploadFile: sinon.spy()
};

const UploadForm = UploadFormFactory({
  '@/lib/api': api
})
```

So your test file will look like:

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import UploadFormFactory from '!!vue-loader?inject!@/components/UploadForm';

describe('upload', () => {
  it('passes form data to api.uploadFile', () => {
    const api = {
      uploadFile: sinon.spy()
    };

    const UploadForm = UploadFormFactory({
      '@/lib/api': api
    })
    const testFormData = { test: 'test' };
    const api = {
      uploadFile: sinon.spy()
    };
    const wrapper = mount(UploadForm);
    wrapper.vm.upload(testFormData);
    expect(api.uploadFile.called).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

**More info**

I've written a tutorial with more detail here - https://www.coding123.org/stub-dependencies-vue-unit-tests/

Comment: you are the man.  Even though I ended up doing it a different way last night, I will definitely be needing this inject-loader method for other things in the future, so thanks a ton for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I think Edd's answer is the most encompassing for most scenarios, so I'm marking his as the accepted answer.  However, the workaround I came up with was to make the api library a global service (`Vue.prototype.$api = api`) in my main.js file, and then overwrite the global with a stub before each test.

```
describe('UploadForm.vue', () => {
  let wrapper;
  const uploadFile = sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve({ data: 0 }));
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(UploadForm, {
      globals: {
        $api: { uploadFile }
      }
    });
  });
  // ...
```